# Files are not getting downloaded with actual name Flask and Google cloud Storage

Tags: flask, google-cloud-storage

I was building a flask app that have a functionality of uploading and downloading files from google cloud storage. For downloading part, I have implemented the following code.

```
def downloadBlob(filename):
    storage_client = storage.Client(project=local_constants.PROJECT_NAME) # my project name here
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(local_constants.PROJECT_STORAGE_BUCKET) # bucket here
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    return blob.download_as_bytes()
```

And I'm calling this function using this code.

```
return Response(downloadBlob(cur_user['root_directory']+cur_dir+file_name), mimetype='application/octet-stream')
```

Where `cur_user['root_directory']` is a 63 bit random number which is different for each user, `cur_dir` is the path to file after 63 bit random number and `file_name` is the file which user have selected to download.

Example of path is `4223099317976595278/test.txt`. This means `4223099317976595278` is the root directory for a user, `/` is the cur_dir and `text.txt` is the file name.

The problem I'm facing is my file is automatically renamed to `download_file`. I tried changing the function `blob.download_as_bytes()` to `blob.download_to_filename()` but it also didn't worked for me.

If the files are in root of cloud storage, they are getting their correct names and if the files are in some other folder, above mentioned issue is happening.

Can anybody point out the mistake or suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: The behavior is normal. So, you need to update your code. What do you expect? Which filename? Can you share a little bit more to easily reproduce your case and help us to help you more easily?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Suppose the file has name "test.txt". When it is downloaded, it must be named as "test.txt" rather than download_file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your browser the file name that you want. For that, you need to add a header named `Content-Disposition` like that (for example)

```
return Response(downloadBlob(cur_user['root_directory']+cur_dir+file_name), mimetype='application/octet-stream', headers={"Content-Disposition": "filename="+file_name})
```

Comment: Thanks, You saved me.